# In Python When updating a file why it gets blank when the code runs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am new with Python . Need some help please. I have a two file one where i run the code from and the other is  credential file. When i am running the below code my credential file gets blank.

So in the below example  i am reading the file first to make sure i can search for key and values. Which is working fine.

```
with open('creds1.py', 'r') as file:
    file = creds1.BTK
    d_items = file.items()   
    for key, value in d_items:
       #print (value)
```

Then on the same code file I am trying to update the key/value on the credential file and during that process my file gets blank. My code to write on the file is

```
    with open('creds1.py', 'w') as fil:
        fil = creds1.BTK
        d1 = {'btk1': value12}
        fil.update(d1)
```

Sorry just to clarify my credential file as mentioned above is a seprate file and i only wanna modify the value for **btk1**

```
cis = {
    'id' : 'C80fb91ec',
    'secret' : 'c10c371b464125b0857'
}

rtk = {
    'tk1' : 'ZTkjdmN2E4OTk5Y2Y5NDEwODgtNjk0_PF84_35d94e6b-f0b4-471b-a49e-b1be74cc008f',
}

BTK = { 
    'btk1' : '**11fgcghvghhjg**'
}
print (d1)
```

Comment: In the second code snippet, why would you use the same name for the `creds.BTK` dict and for the file object?

Comment: So its the same file where my file1 is generating the code,Then i am reading the file and wanna update my key/vlue pair for btk1

Comment: I’m not sure how that addresses my question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The file is blank because you opened it in write mode, but you did not call the `.write(...)` method to write anything to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ta_Req

```
class TK():
        def get_token(self):
            ref_tok = creds.rtk['tk1']
            my_refresh_token = ref_tok
            refresh_token = str(my_refresh_token)
            payload = 'grant_type=refresh_token&client_id='+creds.cis['id']+'&client_secret='+creds.cis['secret']+'&refresh_token='+refresh_token
            print("--------------------------------------")
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'}
            r = requests.post(headers=headers, url='https://testproj.com/v1/a', data=payload)
            #print (r.text)       
            access_token = r.json()['access_token']
            return format(access_token)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BTok = TK().get_token()
```